# How to use TypeScript to map database schema and models?

Tags: typescript

I have a database table called `student`.

```
id | name | createdAt  | deleted
--------------------------------
1  | foo  | 2017-01-13 | false
```

When I retrieve values from the database I will get values mapped to the correct type. I have an interface for this table:

```
interface Student {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  createdAt: Date;
  deleted: boolean;
}
```

To grab values from the database I'm doing something like:

```
await knex('student').where('deleted', false);
```

I'm thinking how to replace the hard-coded strings to refer to the table/columns, so it will be possible to rename/remove columns and detect issues in compile time rather then runtime. I created an object like:

```
const tables = { student: 'student' };
const cols = {
  id: 'id',
  name: 'name',
  createdAt: 'createdAt',
  deleted: 'deleted',
};

await knex(tables.student).where(cols.deleted, false);
```

It works. But the problem with this approach is that if someone change the model interface (`Student`) and forget to change the cols object it is still going to work on compile time.

If I do `const cols: Student` it would validate all columns, but the type for all columns on the `cols` object should be a string.

Is there a way I can do this? Maybe from this line of though or maybe in a completely different approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really easy to fix with the new 2.1.0 features.

```
const tables = { student: 'student' };
const cols: { [P in keyof Student]: string } = {
  id: 'id',
  name: 'name',
  createdAt: 'createdAt',
  deleted: 'deleted',
};

await knex(tables.student).where(cols.deleted, false);
```

This will complain if you change Student, but not the cols object.

Comment: I didn't know about that feature. That's exactly what I need. Sweet!

Comment: You can find more about it here: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript

Answer (score 1):

I can imagine a map-like structure like the following

```
interface MetaDataDescription {
    dbName: string;
    type: any;
}

class StudentMetaData {
    static ID: MetaDataDescription = {dbName: 'id', type: number};
    static NAME: MetaDataDescription = {dbName: 'name', type: string};
    //etc...
}
```

Then you would at runtime generate your interface `Student` from the data (`dbName` for the field name and `type`for the field type) given in `StudentMetaData`. (and likewise for all other models)

Accessing data in this generic interface would be done like `genericInstance[StudentMetaData.ID.dbName]` keeping compile time integrity.

In the query you would then write `await knex(tables.student).where(StudentMetaData.DELETED.dbName, false);`, also keeping compile time checks..

Any change to the whole structure would be in a single point in the metadata class(es),

Comment: This looks a lot like Java EE code in a place where it shouldn't. There's several ways to do it using TypeScript features, no need to engineer a complicated and still not type safe OO system.

Comment: OK, you would lose type safety when assigning to `genericInstance[StudentMetaData.ID.dbName]`, agreed. But even though the `keyof`keyword is pretty slick, you would still end up writing things twice in your solution.

Comment: Sure, but my answer just fixes his code. I'd personally just fix it in a different spot. You can correctly type the where() function to only accept keys of Student. However, since I'm not sure what he's using in terms of architecture and libraries, I can't really provide a solution on that front. 

I'm not saying that my answer is better than yours btw, just that yours seems a bit too... corporate? for my tastes.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile btw, I think, `{dbName: 'id', type: number}` should be `{dbName: 'id', type: Number}`

If that's what you meant, there's also better types than `any` to pick for the interface.

Comment: Just wondering, why use a class with static properties instead of just a plain old JS object? Class in JS is just syntactic sugar for an object with a constructor. Why use a class if you're not going to define a constructor?

Comment: I like classes ;-) JS objects are not precise enough for my liking.

Comment: That's incorrect. It can type objects just fine at compile time.